# turtle in turtlebot_gazebo is not moving

Tags: ros, python, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm new in ROS, and I have a problem with turtlebot_gazebo.

Here I got the code which I would like to use to move the robot.

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
rospy.init_node('red_light_green_light')

red_light_twist = Twist()
green_light_twist = Twist()
green_light_twist.linear.x =5

driving_forward = False
light_change_time = rospy.Time.now()
rate = rospy.Rate(10)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
             if driving_forward:
                        cmd_vel_pub.publish(green_light_twist)
             else:
                        cmd_vel_pub.publish(red_light_twist)
             if light_change_time > rospy.Time.now():
                        driving_forward = not driving_forward
                        light_change_time = rospy.Time.now() + rospy.Duration(3)
             rate.sleep()
```

This is the code from 'Programming robots with ROS' book.

Then in new terminal I use that command

```
./red_light_green_light.py cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
```

and again in new terminal I'm running the code

```
rosrun wanderbot red_light_green_light.py
```

after that in the previous terminal i got this

```
shutdown request: new node registered with the same name
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./red_light_green_light.py", line 25, in <module>
 rate.sleep()
     File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 99, in
    sleep
        sleep(self._remaining(curr_time))
 File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 157, in 
sleep
        raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException("ROS shutdown request")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: ROS shutdown request
```

The turtle in gazebo is not moving. Could someone give some advice? I would be really grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243257/turtle-in-turtlebot_gazebo-is-not-moving/) by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in this line :

```
if light_change_time > rospy.Time.now():
                        driving_forward = not driving_forward
```

should be: `if light_change_time < rospy.Time.now():`

By the way, the author fixed the code here:

https://github.com/osrf/rosbook/blob/master/wanderbot/red_light_green_light.py

---

Originally posted by [harryrobotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/31771/harryrobotic/) with karma: 36 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2